# How are the pre and post increment / decrement operators are evaluated in C++ when they happen to occur repeatedly in a single cout statement?

Tags: c++, evaluation, post-increment, operator-precedence

What is execution strategy that the C++ runtime adopts to produce the  output `4545` when executing the below given code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a=5;
    cout     <<a++     <<++a     <<a--     <<--a;
}
```

I expected the output to be `5444`

Please help me understand how the C++ runtime handles this code.

Comment: It is undefined behavior.

Comment: Is this part of an Indian school curriculum or something? Why do we see this asked almost every day?

Comment: Your program invokes UB. Anything can happen. Compiler can do anything. It might format your hard drive, make your girlfriend pregnant whatever it likes to do !!!

Answer (score 0):

The C++ runtime handles the entire program *however it likes*, because your program has undefined behaviour.

Don't bundle up increment/decrement operations like this.

That's been stated on SO thousands of times!

By the way, the C++ runtime does not "execute" your program; this is not Java. Your CPU executes your program. The C++ runtime is just there to provide libraries and whatnot to support that execution.

Comment: @Destructor: That is not a duplicate.

Comment: It is exact duplicate. It doesn't matter whether you believe it or not.

Comment: @Destructor: It is obviously not an exact duplicate. Perform a text diff on it, or open your eyes, whichever works for you. As a sidenote, going around thinking that other people's input "doesn't matter" is not a good way to live your life.

Comment: Looks like you haven't read answers of that link properly. They cover OP's case exactly.

Comment: Does it really matter whether it's an exact or close duplicate?   Are two dumpsters full of rotting garbage different because the pattern of dents is different?

Comment: ...or, for LRiO's benefit, 'two skips full of rotting garbage' :)

Comment: @MartinJames: You're a Brit too wtf!